# Need to edit coloumn 2 of row 0 of SSCE 3.5 database

Tags: vb.net

I just need to edit coloumn 2 of row 0 of SSCE 3.5 database.  I am using following code.  It generates no error but database is also unchanged.

```
Me.taSet.Fill(Me.Dsset.tblQuestions)
    Dsset.tblQuestions.Rows(0).Item(2) = "EDITED"
    taSet.Update(Dsset.tblQuestions)
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

If the insert and delete statements on your dataset are working, there must be something wrong with you update statement.

Comment: taSet is my table adapter.  What is the data adapter.  I never need it for Adding new row and deleting existing data.  Is it required for Edit?